# Trying to submit a POST request but form is stating its Empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

Been having this issue for a little while now. i have set up the `category_create_post` functionality in the categoryController. i believe everything is done correctly by the looks of it. and also set up the `category_form.ejs` to take in the users input however whenever i submit the form it throws an err saying the category name and description is blank. not able to understand or see why.

thanks

Edit: SOLVED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your headers are set correctly especially `Content-Type`. This heavily depends on the request API you use and the backend.  I usually use `axios` as my request API.